# How to modify element's text to its own text plus extra text in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

E.g:

```
<div class="cloneMyself">clone my self and plus more text</div>
<div class="clickMe">add more info to cloneMyself</div>

$('.clickMe').click(function(){

    $('.cloneMyself').text(// here I want it to be clonMyself's text plus extra info);
});
```

and then when I click `clickMe` ,I need the `cloneMyself's` text to be:

**original text + new text:**

```
clone my self and plus more text from here was added after click it.
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) for info) to query the current element's `.text()`:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
    $('.cloneMyself').text(function() {
        return $(this).text() + " extra info";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(){

    $('.cloneMyself').text($('.cloneMyself').text() + "some extra info");
});
```